# Watching an ObservableList

Tags: dart, dart-polymer

i have an

```
ObservableList<Model> models;
```

and i listen to changes as follows

```
models.listChanges.listen((changes){
      changes.forEach((change){
         print(change);
         List<Model> removedItems = change.removed; //a list of removed objects 
         //how to get a list of the items that have been added?
      });
    });
```

how to get a list of the items that have been added?

and sometimes i get notifications like the following, what does the index actually refer to?

```
#<ListChangeRecord index: 49, removed: [Instance of 'Model', Instance of 'Model'], addedCount: 19>
```

to get the added items my guess is

```
var addedItems = models.getRange(change.index,change.index+change.addedCount);`
```

but is that actually the right way?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yes, that's the way you should use. From the ObservableList source code:

```
    /// [...]
    ///
    /// Each list change record contains information about an individual mutation.
    /// The records are projected so they can be applied sequentially. For
    /// example, this set of mutations:
    ///
    ///     var model = new ObservableList.from(['a', 'b']);
    ///     model.listChanges.listen((records) => records.forEach(print));
    ///     model.removeAt(1);
    ///     model.insertAll(0, ['c', 'd', 'e']);
    ///     model.removeRange(1, 3);
    ///     model.insert(1, 'f');
    ///
    /// The change records will be summarized so they can be "played back", using
    /// the final list positions to figure out which item was added:
    ///
    ///     #<ListChangeRecord index: 0, removed: [], addedCount: 2>
    ///     #<ListChangeRecord index: 3, removed: [b], addedCount: 0>
    ///
    /// [...]
```